# Postgres order column with NaN values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I've got a database in postgres and in few columns (type int) I've got NaN values. When I'm sorting ASC the result is correct, for example:

```
0
1
2
3
4
NaN
```

But when I'm sorting DESC I've got:

```
naN
4
3
2
1
0
```

I know that Postgres treats NaN values as equal, and greater than all non-NaN values, but Is there a way to get this result?

```
4
3
2
1
0
NaN
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your column doesn't contain `NULL`s, you can unambiguously convert NaNs to NULLs and sort on that:

```
select *
from some_table
order by nullif(some_column, 'NaN') desc nulls last
```

Comment: NULLS LAST did the trick :) But does it work for text values too?

Comment: @DanielKoczuła How do you get NaN in a text column?